# automatically add class-type to a factory-class at initialisation

Tags: c#, .net

The problem I am facing: I have a Factory class which has a List of "Writer"s, "Writer" is an abstract class (for now). I have created multiple classes which implement the "Writer" class. Would there be a way, to automatically add the derived classes to the list in the Factory class? Either one of each, or as a Type. Preferably without having to write code into the derived classes (like having to implement a method), and preferably without having to call a method (especially for each individual derived class).

A demo/sample:

```
interface IWriter {
    void Write(string text);
}

class BlockWriter : IWriter {
    //something like this maybe, only this only calls on use of the class so it doesn't work...
    //static BlockWriter() {
    //    Factory.Add(new BlockWriter());
    //}

    public void Write(string text) {
        Console.WriteLine("Block: "  + text);
    }
}

class Factory {
    private static List<IWriter> writers = new List<IWriter>();
    public static List<IWriter> GetWriters() { return writers; }

    // I don't want to have to write every single one down like this.
    // I want a way to do this automatically, like withing the derived classes.
    public static void Build() {
        writers.Add(new BlockWriter());
        writers.Add(new ColumnWriter());
        writers.Add(new LineWriter());
        writers.Add(new SpiralWriter());
        writers.Add(new WaveWriter());
    }

    static Factory() {
        Build();
    }

    public static IWriter ChooseWriter(string input) {
        foreach (IWriter w in writers)
            if (w.GetType().Name.Equals(input))
                return w;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into MEF at all?

Comment: Not really, I'm not sure what that is... I did a quick search, but I'm not sure how it works...

Comment: It sure sounds like you want MEF; I've done factories with that but my approach would likely violate your requirements. Could you post some sample code of how you want to *use* the factory?

Comment: I added some sample code, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure that meets the traditional definition of a factory pattern; but if all you want is to populate that list with one instance of each writer; MEF is *perfect*. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes this is what I need, what did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (oddly enough) the primary purpose of MEF's (Managed Extensibility Framework) `[ImportMany]`. Documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To use it, you first need to mark every implementor of the `IWriter` interface with

```
[Export(typeof(IWriter))]
```

This marks it as a type for MEF to collect (and is *very* easy to forget). Then, you need to mark your collection (`writers`) with `[ImportMany]`:

```
[ImportMany]
private static List<IWriter> writers;
```

Finally, you need to set up a composition container for your assembly, and call `ComposeParts`. MEF will take all the exports it finds that match the type of the generic argument of the list(s) marked with `[ImportMany]` and fill the list(s) with a *single* instance of each matching exported type.

```
//An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
//Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Factory class
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Factory).Assembly));

//Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

//Fill the lists
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Most of that code came from the linked MSDN page.

Comment: @Ken no problem; glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little bit more research and found a simpler answer using reflection in factory pattern.

```
public static IWriter ChooseWriter(string writer)
{
    Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var currentType = currentAssembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == writer);
    return (IWriter )Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);
}
```

http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/factory-pattern-with-reflection-c/ or
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37547/Exploring-Factory-Pattern (last implementation (4th))

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is a plugin architecture.

This can pretty easily be achieved with an Ioc container like [Autofac](http://autofac.org) or [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110%29.aspx) (not strictly an Ioc container).

I would prefer MEF in this scenario as it has better support for type discovery.